# Duplicate Logs in log file

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, log4j, weblogic11g

I'm facing lot of problem in log4j logging..
Whenever I stop a build on Weblogic console and Resume it back it generates double logs.
Here are the logs:

```
[21 Jul 2014 11:03:30,053] INFO  [T006]   - Creating connection to [127.0.0.1:6582]
[21 Jul 2014 11:03:30,054] INFO  [T006]   - Connection established [127.0.0.1:6582]
[21 Jul 2014 11:03:30,054] INFO  [T006]   - Creating connection to [127.0.0.1:6583]
[21 Jul 2014 11:03:30,055] INFO  [T006]   - Connection established [127.0.0.1:6583]
[21 Jul 2014 11:03:30,055] INFO  [T006]   - Creating connection to [127.0.0.1:6584]
[21 Jul 2014 11:03:30,055] INFO  [T006]   - Connection established [127.0.0.1:6584]
[21 Jul 2014 11:03:30,950] INFO  [T006]   - Response Q connected...
[21 Jul 2014 11:03:30,975] INFO  [T006]   - Request Queue Connected.
[21 Jul 2014 11:03:30,980] INFO  [T006]   - Message Timeout Monitor is Started for T006
[21 Jul 2014 11:04:28,736] INFO  [T006]   - Destroying messageTimeoutMonitor Thread.
[21 Jul 2014 11:04:28,736] INFO  [T006]   - Destroying keepAlive Thread.
[21 Jul 2014 11:04:28,736] INFO  [T006]   - Receiver Thread Shutdown on port 6582
[21 Jul 2014 11:04:28,737] INFO  [T006]   - Receiver Thread Shutdown on port 6583
[21 Jul 2014 11:04:28,737] INFO  [T006]   - Receiver Thread Shutdown on port 6584
[21 Jul 2014 11:05:08,898] INFO  [T006]   - Creating connection to [127.0.0.1:6582]
[21 Jul 2014 11:05:08,898] INFO  [T006]   - Creating connection to [127.0.0.1:6582]
[21 Jul 2014 11:05:08,898] INFO  [T006]   - Connection established [127.0.0.1:6582]
[21 Jul 2014 11:05:08,898] INFO  [T006]   - Connection established [127.0.0.1:6582]
[21 Jul 2014 11:05:08,899] INFO  [T006]   - Creating connection to [127.0.0.1:6583]
[21 Jul 2014 11:05:08,899] INFO  [T006]   - Creating connection to [127.0.0.1:6583]
[21 Jul 2014 11:05:08,899] INFO  [T006]   - Connection established [127.0.0.1:6583]
[21 Jul 2014 11:05:08,899] INFO  [T006]   - Connection established [127.0.0.1:6583]
[21 Jul 2014 11:05:08,899] INFO  [T006]   - Creating connection to [127.0.0.1:6584]
[21 Jul 2014 11:05:08,899] INFO  [T006]   - Creating connection to [127.0.0.1:6584]
[21 Jul 2014 11:05:08,899] INFO  [T006]   - Connection established [127.0.0.1:6584]
[21 Jul 2014 11:05:08,899] INFO  [T006]   - Connection established [127.0.0.1:6584]
[21 Jul 2014 11:05:08,911] INFO  [T006]   - Response Q connected...
[21 Jul 2014 11:05:08,911] INFO  [T006]   - Response Q connected...
[21 Jul 2014 11:05:08,917] INFO  [T006]   - Request Queue Connected.
[21 Jul 2014 11:05:08,917] INFO  [T006]   - Request Queue Connected.
[21 Jul 2014 11:05:08,924] INFO  [T006]   - Message Timeout Monitor is Started for T006
[21 Jul 2014 11:05:08,924] INFO  [T006]   - Message Timeout Monitor is Started for T006
```

I hvn't made log4j configuration in XML. I have done through code.
What is the solution?

Here Is the Code:
Log4jConfiguration Class
    public class Log4jConfigurationBean {
        private String logLevel;
        private String path;
        private String fileName;
        private String errorFileName;
        private String applicationName;

```
    public Level getLogLevel() {
        Level level = null;
        if(logLevel=="debug")
            level = Level.DEBUG;
        else if(logLevel.equalsIgnoreCase("all"))
            level = Level.ALL;
        else if(logLevel.equalsIgnoreCase("warn"))
            level = Level.WARN;
        else if(logLevel.equalsIgnoreCase("info"))
            level = Level.INFO;
        else if(logLevel.equalsIgnoreCase("error"))
            level = Level.ERROR;
        else if(logLevel.equalsIgnoreCase("debug"))
            level = Level.DEBUG;
        else if(logLevel.equalsIgnoreCase("trace"))
            level = Level.TRACE;

        return level;
    }
```

Socket Logger Class
    public class SocketLogger{

```
    private static SingletonStaticContainer singletonStaticContainer = SingletonStaticContainer.getInstance();

    public void configureLogger(Log4jConfigurationBean log4jConfiguration){


                PatternLayout otherLayout = new PatternLayout(
                        "[%d{DATE}] %-5p ["+log4jConfiguration.getApplicationName()+"]  %x - %m%n"
                        );

                PatternLayout errorLayout = new PatternLayout(
                        //"[%d{DATE}] %-5p %l  ["+log4jConfiguration.getApplicationName()+"]  %x - %m%n"
                        "[%d{DATE}] %-5p ["+log4jConfiguration.getApplicationName()+"]  %x - %m%n"
                        );

                //remove console laout not using anymore
                //rootLogger.addAppender(new ConsoleAppender(otherLayout));

                try {
                    //creating error file appender
                    RollingFileAppender errorAppender = new RollingFileAppender(errorLayout,log4jConfiguration.getPath()+log4jConfiguration.getErrorFileName());
                    errorAppender.setMaxFileSize("200MB");
                    errorAppender.activateOptions();
                    errorAppender.addFilter(new ErrorFilter());

                    //creating fileappender for other then error messages
                    RollingFileAppender fileAppender = new RollingFileAppender(otherLayout,log4jConfiguration.getPath()+log4jConfiguration.getFileName());
                    fileAppender.setMaxFileSize("200MB");
                    fileAppender.activateOptions();
                    fileAppender.addFilter(new CustomFilter());

                    Logger rootLogger = Logger.getLogger(singletonStaticContainer.getInstance().applicationName);


                    rootLogger.setLevel(log4jConfiguration.getLogLevel());
                    rootLogger.addAppender(errorAppender);
                    rootLogger.addAppender(fileAppender);

                    Logger.getLogger(singletonStaticContainer.applicationName);
                    Logger rootLogger = Logger.getLogger(SocketLogger.class);

                    rootLogger.setLevel(log4jConfiguration.getLogLevel());
                    rootLogger.addAppender(errorAppender);
                    rootLogger.addAppender(fileAppender);*/


                    //remove console laout not using anymore
                    //rootLogger.addAppender(new ConsoleAppender(otherLayout));


                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

    }

}
```

Comment: please show the code with log4j loggers in code?

Comment: It seems you have two loggers writing to the same log file. Please share your log4j config file. Also, check if you are redirecting your stdout to this file as well.

Comment: @Sanjeev i have posted the code.

Comment: @Pat i have posted the code